# location finder using ios

Tags: objective-c, iphone

This is my code below.
This is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ShowmyLocation : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Longitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Latitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *MyAddress;
- (IBAction)getlocation:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

@end

This is my .m file

```
#import "ShowmyLocation.h"

@interface ShowmyLocation ()

@end

@implementation ShowmyLocation
{
    //CLLocationManager *locationmanager;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder;
    CLPlacemark *placemark;
}
@synthesize Longitude;
@synthesize Latitude;
@synthesize MyAddress;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector
         (requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)getlocation:(id)sender {
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(CLLocation *)newLocation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [newLocation coordinate];
    NSLog( @"We're at %f, %f\n", loc.latitude, loc.longitude );
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    //NSLog(@"location info object=%@", newLocation);
    //CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    Longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", loc.latitude];
    Latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", loc.longitude];


}
```

I have included requestWhenInUseAuthorization in info.plist file.

When I click on getlocation it returns nothing.
I am using xcode 6.2 and running on a  simmulator iphone 6/ios 8.2

Can anyone help me out as to what I am missing. I am pretty new in IOS development.

Comment: Go to your simulator and uder menu Debug->Locations-> Select anything except none and try again

Comment: I also suggest you to remove '[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];' under viewDidLoad as you are calling it on button click.

Comment: It was selected Mumbai

Comment: Even after deleting in the viewdidLoad it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
- (IBAction)getlocation:(id)sender {

    if (nil == locationManager)      
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 500; // meters
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}


   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

      CLLocation *newLocation = locations.lastObject;    
      NSLog(@"Latitude===%f ::", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
      NSLog(@"Longitude===%f ::", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you calling **startUpdatingLocation** twice in *viewDidLoad* and *IBAction*. I would think you may consider creating a method for your location update so that you can have the location authorisation part necessary for iOS8 before calling **startUpdatingLocation**. It may look something like this:

```
- (void)startStandardUpdates {

    if (nil == locationManager) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }

    locationManager.delegate = self;

    // This part was added due to a location authorization issue on iOS8
    // See more at: http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/
    if ([self._locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self._locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocation *currentLocation = locationManager.location;
    if (currentLocation) {
        PAWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        appDelegate.currentLocation = currentLocation;
    }

}
```

One more thing, as you're testing on simulator, please try **Debug->Location Service** also. Hope this helps.

Comment: how do i call startStandardUpdates from my button

Comment: `[self startStandardUpdates];` in your IBAction

Answer (score -1):

Please try below solution hope this is work for you.

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue]>=8.0)
{
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    // If the status is denied or only granted for when in use, display an alert
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        if (!isShowAlertView) {
            NSString *title = (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) ? @"Location services are off" : @"Background location is not enabled";
            NSString *message = @"To use background location you must turn on 'Always' in the Location Services Settings";
        }
    }
    // The user has not enabled any location services. Request background authorization.
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [[APPDELEGATE locationManager] requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
}
else{
    switch ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
            NSLog(@"Authorized Always");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
            NSLog(@"Authorized when in use");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        {
            NSLog(@"Denied");
            if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
            }
            else {
                NSString *message = @"To use background location you must turn on 'Always' in the Location Services Settings";
            }
        }
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            NSLog(@"Not determined");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            NSLog(@"Restricted");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

//Delegate Methods of CLLocationManager
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:
(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Latitude:- %f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"Longitude:- %f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error:- %@“,[error description]);
}
```

Thank You..

Comment: though the system is going into the if condition of appdelegate the required result is not shown